# How to store list of string with sharedpreferences in Flutter?

Tags: list, flutter, dart, listview, sharedpreferences

I've a list of string that I've insert into a ListView in Flutter:

How can I store the list with sharedPreferences and use it in the ListView?

Comment: you can json encode list to string or join your list list.join(" ")

Answer (score 0):

Declare your variables

```
List<Todo> list = new List<Todo>();
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
```

Save data into SharedPreferences after converting to json

```
void saveData(){
  List<String> stringList = list.map(
    (item) => json.encode(item.toMap()
  )).toList();
  sharedPreferences.setStringList('list', stringList);
}
```

Load data from SharedPreferences and convert back

```
void loadData() {
  List<String> listString = sharedPreferences.getStringList('list');
  if(listString != null){
    list = listString.map(
      (item) => Todo.fromMap(json.decode(item))
    ).toList();
    setState((){});
  }
}
```